# IOS Dynamic Framework, External symbols become Non-External for Release Build

Tags: ios, xcode, dynamic, frameworks

I have built a Dynamic Framework to use in various projects. Everything was working nicely when I was developing with a Debug build but when I built a release version I had errors with Arm64 symbols being missing. The framework is built as a universal framework and on inspection it does contain the symbols, the difference is that when compiled as Release, the External Symbols change to Non-External.

Using nm -m myframework.framework/myFramework

For example: 
in debug, the sybol files might look like this:
(__TEXT,__text) external [Thumb] _SomeSymbolName

But in Release they look like this:

(__TEXT,__text) non-external (was a private external) [Thumb] _SomeSymbolName

Any Ideas why this might be? Or any build settings that would cause that?

Answer (score 1):

The Solution was to disable

"Symbols Hidden By Default"

in Build settings